# python equivalent to matlab mvnrnd?

Tags: python, matlab, covariance, normal-distribution

I was just wondering how to go from `mvnrnd([4 3], [.4 1.2], 300);` in MATLAB code to `np.random.multivariate_normal([4,3], [[x_1 x_2],[x_3 x_4]], 300)` in Python.

My doubt namely lays on the sigma parameter, since, in MATLAB, a 2D vector is used to specify the covariance; whereas, in Python, a matrix must be used. 
What is the theoretical meaning on that and what is the practical approach to go from one to another, for instance, in this case? Also, is there a rapid, mechanical way?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Although python expects a matrix, it is essentially a symmetric covariance matrix. So it has to be a square matrix. 
In 2x2 case, a symmetric matrix will have mirrored non diagonal elements.

I believe in python, it should look like [[.4 1.2],[1.2 .4]]

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer!